# static vs enum which should I use in swift

Tags: swift, struct, enums, static

iOS 12, Swift 4.2

Both of these do the same thing, which is better?

```
private struct fieldV {
  static let billV = 1
  static let centV = 2
  static let payerV = 3
}

private enum fieldInt: Int {
  case bill
  case cent
  case payers
}
```

To use the first is a little more obvious, so I got this.

```
percent.tag = fieldV.centV
```

**vs**

`percent.tag = fieldInt.cent.rawValue`

Sure I am talking about 3 different Ints vs a single Int that can have one of three values? But is there a better reason to use one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Struct and enums are fundamentally different in the sense that :

1. Structs like classes are product types. This means to represent an object of a struct you need all the fields. For example lets take a struct **Employee** with two fields name and address. An employee in this case is *defined* by both address and name.
2. On the other hand enums are sum type. This means they are represented by any of the field. For example let's take an enum **NetworkStatus** which can be *either* SUCCESS or FAILURE

Notice that in struct (and also classes, tuples) information representation happens by *all* of their fields while in case of enums information representation happens by *any* of their fields.

In your case clearly **structs** is the correct answer as you need *bill, cent and payers* **all** three of the fields to represent the complete information.

Answer (score 1):

When you have limited **known** options, you should use **enum**. **Enum** can be `CaseIterable` and you can use it cases `all` at once! You can `switch` on an enum and it automatically tracks adding and removing of cases if you don't use `default` case. These are not possible with `struct` or class. Even if you want to use `Int` value directly without `rawValue` you should consider using **static inside enum** like this:

```
private enum Field {
  static let bill = 1
  static let cent = 2
  static let payer = 3
}
```

As your case naming, It looks like `Int` value is something that you want to compare or something you should send to server or etc. and it's not part of the `Field` itself. So I recommend you to use some computed property except rawValue instead!

```
private enum Field {
    case bill
    case cent
    case payers

    var intValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .bill: return 1
        case .cent: return 2
        case .payers: return 3
        }
    }
}
```

It may cause you more time and writing, but it's more convenient and bug-proof. You can add a custom initializer if you want.

### - **One More Thing**

In swift, you should consider using **upper camel case** names for types. (Enum, Struct, Class)

Comment: I am getting .Type instead of all the keys

Comment: Please explain more